# Basic reverse-proxy in Docker: Forbidden (no permission)

Tags: php, apache, docker, nginx, proxy

I start jwilder nginx proxy on 8080

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

I'm running a standard `php:apache` container without mapping the port (so 80 is exposed on the container network).
I use an env var to connect with the proxy:

```
docker run -d -e VIRTUAL_HOST=test.example.com php:apache
```

on my localhost I've added this in /etc/hosts:

```
IP test.example.com
```

Now I visit `text.example.com:8080` on my computer so I try to connect with the reverse proxy (8080) which will route me to php-apache on container port 80.

But I get this error:

Error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at test.example.com Port 8080
```

What am I missing? Do I have the change the apache configuration somewhere? (it's now all default). It seems to go throught the nginx because I'm seeing an apache error so I think I need to tell the apache inside (php apache): Allow this 'route')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title appears to be misleading. From your description, you've setup a properly functioning reverse proxy and the target you are connecting to with your reverse proxy is broken. If you review the [docker hub page on the php:apache image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) you'll find multiple examples for how to load your php code into the image and get it working. E.g.:

```
$ docker run -d -e VIRTUAL_HOST=test.example.com \
  -v "$PWD/your/php/code/dir":/var/www/html php:7.0-apache
```

Comment: Wow, my question looks stupid now. It thought it had nothing to do with the code I would mount (I was expecting the default: 'It works!')

Comment: And if I want to use SSL? Do I just have to mount the SSL scripts to this proxy or do I need to configure files too?

Comment: @DenCowboy You'd typically configure TLS termination on the proxy server, mounting your certificates and updating configuration files in there. You won't be able to pass through traffic without terminating unless your clients all have SNI.